# Using NSScanner to parse a NSString returns duplicate end of element result

Tags: ios, swift

I am using NSScanner to parse the text between  "[a]" and "[/a]". And in my example, 1 input can contains multiple instances of some text , so I need to do that in a loop.
Here is my code:

```
            var datastring = "test [a]1[/a][a]2[/a] [a]3[/a][a]4[/a] end"
            var len = countElements(datastring)
            let scanner = NSScanner(string: datastring)

            var itemResult : NSString?
            // loop until scanner reaches the end of string
            while (scanner.scanLocation < len) {
                scanner.scanUpToString("<a>", intoString: nil)

                // len of "[a]" is 3
                if (len - scanner.scanLocation > 3) {
                    scanner.scanLocation += 3
                }
                scanner.scanUpToString("[/a]", intoString: &itemResult)
                 // len of "[/a]" is 3
                if (len - scanner.scanLocation > 4) {
                    scanner.scanLocation += 4
                }
                if (itemResult != nil) {
                    println(itemResult!)
                }
            }
```

Here is the output:

```
1
2
]3
4
4
```

It kinds of works, but I see 2 problem
1. 4 repeats 1 more time
2. instead of "3", it returns "]3" I think that is caused by the extra space in the "[/a] [/a]"

can you please tell me how to why NSScanner can't 
1. skip the exta space when it looks for "[a]"
2. why it returns 4 twice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can explain this.

First the ">3".  In this part of the string `"2</a> <a>3"` after printing "2" the scanLocation moves 4 characters to just before the space.  The next time through the loop, you increment the scanLocation 3 spaces.  From before the space to just before the >3.  So when you scan for the next `</a>`, you place >3 into your string.

Now for the repeat printing of the number 4.  After writing 4 once, the loop continues another time.  While you do not find any more `<a> or </a>`, itemResult still contains the value 4 from the previous time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

@MinnesotaSteve hits all the important points. Here is an improved version.

```
extension NSScanner {
  func scanThrough(string: String, intoString:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>) -> Bool {
    self.scanUpToString(string, intoString: intoString)
    return self.scanString(string, intoString: nil)
  }
}

let datastring = "test [a]1[/a][a]2[/a] [a]3[/a][a]4[/a] end"
let scanner = NSScanner(string: datastring)

while !scanner.atEnd {
  var itemResult : NSString?
  if scanner.scanThrough("[a]", intoString:nil)
    && scanner.scanThrough("[/a]", intoString: &itemResult)
    && itemResult != nil {
      println(itemResult!)
  }
}
```